# Reduced random effect variance by adding more covariates

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

I'm having a hard time understanding the situation where the variance for the random effect decreased as more predictors were included.

For example, the model below has only two predictors, and its random effect SD is **1.205**.

[image: Two predictors]

However, when three predictors were added, as shown below, the random effect SD dropped by **0.929**.

[image]

Someone explained this pattern as suggesting that the distribution of one or more predictors varies across Level-2 clusters (communities in this case). However, I cannot fully understand what it means.

Looking for more detailed explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Could your provide info on what the variables here mean? For example, what is `meduc2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like some of the variation between the communities is explained by the three additional predictors.

For example, suppose that `wealthc` is a strong predictor of your response variable, and its average value varies a lot between communities. If you don't have `wealthc` in your model, you can see that the communities have different outcomes but you don't know why. Once you include it in the model, the variability between communities decreases, hence the drop in random effect SD.

Comment: Thank you so much!